# pagebreak on .epub does not work on uiwebview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, epub

I am creating an epub reader on ios. I'm able to show the epub in the uiwebview but the size of the epub doest not fit on uiwebview. It appears the epub file is bigger and not proportion in webview. What should I do to resize it? Thanks.

This is my code.

vCover = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

```
CGRect frame = busyLoad.frame;
frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2;
frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
busyLoad.frame = frame;


[self.view addSubview:vCover];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:vCover];
[self.view addSubview:busyLoad];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:busyLoad];
[busyLoad startAnimating];
int offset = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", todo.htmOffset]intValue]*webView.bounds.size.height;

NSLog(@"pageH:%f ", webView.bounds.size.height);

UIScrollView *scrollview    = (UIScrollView *)[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollview.contentInset     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0,0.0,44.0,0.0);
NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, %d);", offset];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.margin='50';";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];
NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", 100];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];
NSLog(@"DidLoad:%d", offset);

[webView setHidden:NO];



[busyLoad removeFromSuperview];
[vCover removeFromSuperview];
[busyLoad stopAnimating];
```

Comment: can you share how are you setting the file into UIWebView

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! I notice that the page break after-always does not working in uiwebview. I have a sample epub book that can be read by ibooks properly. Thanks.

Comment: hi @user3205472 how can we break the pages from an book.html file in UIWebView in iOS please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Hi there!!,
>
> You can do pagination like ios7 pagination property of UIScrollView
> (i.e webview.scrollview.pagingEnabled = yes) using below methods.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
    [self setPagination:self];
    }
    
    - (void) setPagination:(UIWebView *) webView
    {
        NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";
        
        NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
        "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
        "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
        "}";
        
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
        NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
        
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];
        
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];
        
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
        
        
        CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"] floatValue],
                                        [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]);
        int pageCount = contentSize.width/webView.frame.size.width;
        
    //move to page using offset
    //            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    //            point = CGPointMake(indexOfPage*webView.frame.size.width, 0);
    //            self.scrollView.contentOffset = point;
        
    }
```